# Log4j using two different logs in the same class

Tags: java, log4j

I have the following configs for my logs :

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, RollLogFile
log4j.logger.ReportLog=INFO,ReportLog
```

After, i set two appenders for my logs and some properties. 
Im doing this in my code:

```
reportLogger = LogManager.getLogger("ReportLog");
```

And after that

```
reportLogger.info("blabla bla bla ");
```

Why this line is also logged in RollLogFile`s file?

Answer (score 1):

Because of *Appender additivity*:

> **Each enabled logging request for a given logger will be forwarded to all the appenders in that logger as well as the appenders higher in
>   the hierarchy**. In other words, appenders are inherited additively
>   from the logger hierarchy. For example, if a console appender is added
>   to the root logger, then all enabled logging requests will at least
>   print on the console. If in addition a file appender is added to a
>   logger, say C, then enabled logging requests for C and C's children
>   will print on a file and on the console. It is possible to override
>   this default behavior so that appender accumulation is no longer
>   additive by [setting the additivity flag](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Category.html#setAdditivity(boolean)) to `false`.